# How can I read only certain CSV files from my s3 bucket? Is that even possble?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3

Here is my code:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket-name')
prefix_df=['bpr2','bpr6','bprc','bpuu','tap000','tap020']

def get_rowcount_csv():
    for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='decrypted/'):
        if my_bucket_object.key.endswith('.csv'):
            filename = my_bucket_object.key.split('/')[-1]
            df = pd.read_csv(f's3://csv/path/to/file/{filename}', sep='|')
            numlines=len(df)
            print(f'{filename} ' + ":" f' {numlines}')

get_rowcount_csv()
```

It iterates through all the csv files in my s3 bucket and does a row count of each one. The problem is that my s3 bucket has over 50 csv files and I only want to read 6 of them. I can't use the "prefix" feature to only select those 6 in the s3 bucket because the names of the csv files have almost the same prefix. I tried making a list called `prefix_df` that my code could read to only select the csv files that have names like in that list but it didn't return anything.

Here are the CSV files I have:

```
BPR2.csv
BPR6.csv
BPRC.csv
BPRT.csv
BPUU.csv
TAP000.csv
TAP020.csv
```

I want to read all of them except for `BPRT.csv`. The list is longer but this is how the naming convention is set up, the names are very close to each other so I don't know how to pick those out.

Comment: You'll have to find some method of identifying the 7 CSVs you want to read.  Then you can just skip the ones that you don't want to read.  If you need help, share examples of the CSVs you do and don't want to read

Comment: i updated my OP with the csv file examples i want to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a better way to do it but here's how you can do it with the code you provided.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket-name')
prefix_df=['tablename','tablename2','tablename3','tablename4','tablename5','tablename6','tablename7']

def get_rowcount_csv():
    for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='decrypted/'):
        if my_bucket_object.key.endswith('.csv'):
            filename = my_bucket_object.key.split('/')[-1]

            # Check if the filename is in your list
            if filename.split('.')[0] in prefix_df:
                df = pd.read_csv(f's3://csv/path/to/file/{filename}', sep='|')
                numlines=len(df)
                print(f'{filename} ' + ":" f' {numlines}')

get_rowcount_csv()
```

---

**Edit**

The other way around, skipping what you don't want to read.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket-name')
dont_want_filters=['BPU', 'BPRT']

def get_rowcount_csv():
    for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='decrypted/'):
        if my_bucket_object.key.endswith('.csv'):
            filename = my_bucket_object.key.split('/')[-1]

            # True if the filename contains string from the filters
            flagged = bool([f for f in dont_want_filters if f in filename])  

            if not flagged:
                df = pd.read_csv(f's3://csv/path/to/file/{filename}', sep='|')
                numlines=len(df)
                print(f'{filename} ' + ":" f' {numlines}')

get_rowcount_csv()


# In your example csv list, BPRT.csv and BPUU.csv will be skipped.
```

Comment: Welcome. I added a different approach, where you can filter what you don't want to read. Feel free to mark this an answer if this helps you. Thanks!